# File extension types in PERL code in linux server

Tags: database, file, perl

I am working in an email campaign web UI product which sends mails campaign to end users. It maintains the end user email addresses and remaining details in Oracle tables,for example the table T_list holds the audience id(CID is the customerID), the same table has other column which contains the table name as its value like 't_member_year_month_dd_time' in the oracle DB,as both t_list and t_member tables are in foreign key relation based on the CID column. There are 2 tables : t_list t_member_year_month_dd_time

To show the basic scenario I provided 2 table names, basically there are more number of t_member tables in the product for multiple clients.

To maintain all these existing audience tables and for new audience tales creation procedure, there exists a backend perl code which refreshes the existing lists/audiences as well as new lists creation. Please find the PERL process flow as in the attached screenshot :
[image]

In the whole scenario I am having doubts regarding the file extension types .pre, .sor, .idx, .rfa, what are these file extensions referring to. Are these specific to technology related or our own extension to save in Linux servers for fast processing based on the requirement.

Comment: "millions of mails" -- so basically your company sends spam email?

Comment: HI @TLP, I corrected that one, any idea on file extensions please

Comment: @JRFerguson, It seems the details provided in this post is enough to understand my problem, If you agree please have a look on these details and please suggest on file extensions.

Comment: The application's documentation should answer your question about the various file extensions. File extensions in Linux are used to determine which program to use to open a data file.

Comment: @JRFerguson, Thank you for the reply,Before I posting my question here I verified the documents and perl programs for the same requirement, I could not get it, what I understood is the perl code stores the minimized way of customer records storing in index files, as I am a coldfusion developer not able to understand it, so can you please provide more details on file extensions in linux server with perl code If possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any extension you want on a file. Extensions make it easier to open a document with an appropriate program, but it's not mandatory that a file is correctly associated. You didn't indicate what type of files those are, but they appear to all contain tabular data, so I imagine they all use the same format. The extension is used to differentiate the contents, not the format.

So,

- As you said, `.sor` is used for the *sor*ted data.
- `.pre` could refer to *pre*-sorted data.
- `.idx` could refer to *i*n*d*e*x*.
- I can't guess what `.rfa` could mean.

Comment: Yes, It seems these extensions are app specific. Thank you

Comment: the .rfa file is a descriptor file to tell where in the index file the start and stop values of all items of interest are. In the attached image the last one is the .rfa file example, where 1234 is the list item, 0 and 4 represents it's the list item '1234' start and end positions, Thank you for the response and understanding, every one is down voted my question rather than suggesting, it's also my mistake too.

Comment: People are a bit to eager to hand out downvotes in my opinion. But the question is a bit incomplete. It would have been nice to know more about the actual files, since that's what you're asking about. A snippet of the actual files (perhaps from `hexdump -C`) would likely have been useful. By the way, there's a unixy tool call `file` which guesses a file's type.

Comment: one last doubt is when I try to open one of the abc.idx file, it's not in valid format(I can see it's content as        èÂ       èÂ       èÂ ), can't we open these files directly to read it's content?

Comment: I can't tell what file format it is from that. See my previous comment.

Comment: ok, looking into the code, TQ